# Finding the value of $\frac{13}{a-13}+\frac{23}{b-23}+\frac{42}{c-42} $ given a system of three equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a, b, c, x, y, z$ be real numbers that satisfy the three equations

$$ 13x+by+cz=0 $$
$$ ax+23y+cz=0 $$
$$ ax+by+42z=0 $$

Suppose that $ a\neq13 $ and $x\neq0$. What is the value of $$\frac{13}{a-13}+\frac{23}{b-23}+\frac{42}{c-42} $$

---

I tried

$$ (13-a)x+(b-23)y=0 $$
$$ (23-b)y+(c-42)z=0 $$
$$ (13-a)x+(c-42)z=0 $$

---

$$ (a-13)x=(b-23)y=(c-42)z $$

But I don't know how to continue further

Maybe

$$ \frac{1}{(a-13)x}=\frac{1}{(b-23)y}=\frac{1}{(c-42)z} $$

But any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Whats the answer? Is it -2

Comment: @Manthanein yeah, can you give me the hint though?

Comment: You have obtained 3 linear equations in x,y ; y, z; and x, z. So try expressing y, z in terms of x.  Now substitute the values if y, z in the first equation of all 3 original equations. Then factor out the x from obtained expression and since x  is not equal to 0 then the other factor must be 0. So set that factor equal to 0 and continue with further algebra.  You will automatically get the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current progress is excellent.

Note that $$\frac{1}{(a-13)x}=\frac{1}{(b-23)y}=\frac{1}{(c-42)z}$$ means that $$\frac{13}{a-13}+\frac{23}{b-23}+\frac{42}{c-42}=\frac{13x}{(a-13)x}+\frac{23y}{(b-23)y}+\frac{42z}{(c-42)z}$$ or that $$\frac{13}{a-13}+\frac{23}{b-23}+\frac{42}{c-42}=\frac{13x+23y+42z}{(a-13)x}$$ due to the equalities.

Adding the three equations given gives $$13x+23y+42z=-2(ax+by+cz)=-2(ax-13x)=-2x(a-13)$$ from the first equation hence $$\boxed{\frac{13}{a-13}+\frac{23}{b-23}+\frac{42}{c-42}=\frac{-2(a-13)x}{(a-13)x}=-2}$$

**P.S.** The values of $13,23,42$ are totally arbitrary. This works for any triplet of non-zero integers.